# Facebook share and custom text with image

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using facebook sdk

```
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
```

and using method

```
FB.ui({
   method: "send", 
   link: 'http://test.com/'
});
```

Is there is any option to send text and image
I also used

```
FB.ui({
  method: "send", 
  link: 'http://test.com/',
  description: 'custom text hello this is my content',
  picture: 'hello.jpg'
});
```

but this is not working there is FB.ui method pickup automatically text and image from link but I need to send custom please help if is there

Answer (score 1):

The send method/dialog does not accept a 'picture' parameter.

[Facebook Javascript SDK Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog)

Comment: No, the API documentation doesn't mention anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

The send dialog only allows you to add a link, the Open Graph data of that link will be used. There is no way to use custom data for the link.

Send Dialog parameters:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

Open Graph tags:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags
- http://ogp.me/

Keep in mind that users should know what they can expect behind the link, so it´s a bad idea to use custom data instead of existing Open Graph data directly from the link.

Answer (score -2):

```
<a title="send to Facebook" 
  href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=YOUR_TITLE&p[summary]=YOUR_SUMMARY&p[url]=YOUR_URL&p[images][0]=YOUR_IMAGE_TO_SHARE_OBJECT"
  target="_blank">
  <span>
    <img width="14" height="14" src="'icons/fb.gif" alt="Facebook" /> Facebook 
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: I just want to send personal message

Comment: the sharer does not accept any other parameters than the url. those additional parameters are not available anymore since many years. also, he is talking about sending, not sharing. there´s a difference.